# Игнорирование версии PHP при запуске команд php artisan

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Есть проект Laravel.
На локальной машине стоит версия php 8.0 и никаких проблем, на сервере php v 7.4.29 и при запуске команды `php composer clear-cache` выдает:

```
Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2". You are running 7.4.29. in *\vendor\composer\platform_check.php on line 24
```

Composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": "8.*",
    "ext-json": "*",
```

Обновить версию php на сервере нет возможности, можно ли игнорировать версию php при запуске php composer команд?

Comment: Попробовать можно заменив "php": "8.*" на "php": "7.*". Но гарантий нет, что всё будет корректно работать

Comment: Ничего не изменилось

Comment: скорее, не будет, поскольку это требование программы, вероятно, она написана в расчете на 8

Comment: она запускается и работает на 7 версии на сервере, но при запуске "php composer clear-cache" или подобных команд говорит, что php нужен 8 версии

Comment: @Максим Вам composer нужен для php 7 ну и laravel такой же

Comment: разрабатывать проект и эксплуатировать его на разных версиях пхп довольно занятная идея.

Comment: Согласен) Но это не моя идея, приходится работать с тем, что есть!